# Redirect back to the app Issue after paytm payment success in web using node js

Tags: node.js, payment, paytm

Implemented paytm payment logic in nodejs. After successful payment it is not redirecting to success message simply it is showing "Redirect back to the page" in prod environment. Below is my code. Also attached screenshot. Please help me if i miss anything.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XijEH.png)

```
 app.post('/payment', urlencodedParser, (req,res)=>{

    let reqbody = req.body;
    let orderId = 'order_'+ Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    let params = {}
    params['MID'] = 'My Merchant Id',
    params['WEBSITE'] = 'DEFAULT',
    params['CHANNEL_ID'] = 'WEB',
    params['INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID'] = 'Retail',
    params['ORDER_ID'] = orderId,
    params['CUST_ID'] = 'CUST' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
    params['TXN_AMOUNT'] = '1',//+reqbody.money+'',
    params['CALLBACK_URL'] = 'https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID='+orderId+'',
    params['EMAIL'] = 'myemail@gmail.com',
    params['MOBILE_NO'] = '9999999999',

    checksum_lib.genchecksum(params, '9KBKBVjiB3ml5TSP', function(err, checksum){
        let txn_url = 'https://securegw.paytm.in/order/process';
        let form_fields =''
        for(x in params){
            form_fields +="<input type='hidden' name = '"+x+"' value = '"+params[x]+"'/>"
        }

        form_fields +="<input type='hidden' name = 'CHECKSUMHASH' value = '"+checksum+"' />" 

        var html = '<html><body><center><h1>Please wait! Do not refresh the page </h1></center><form method="post" action="'+txn_url+'" name="f1">'+form_fields+'<script type="text/javascript">document.f1.submit()</script></body></html>'

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'})    
        res.write(html)
        res.end()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use your own call back URL instead of  https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=. 
Above call back URL work only for app. So you need to replace your own call back URL in the parameter params['CALLBACK_URL'].

Comment: Thanks Ravindra. Working fine.

Comment: I tried the code ! I used the callback URL perfectly, but the callback is not sending any data in the req.body. Normally it should mainly contain req.body.CHECKSUMHASH

So i also tried to log req.body and it gives an empty object like : { }

What to do ?